# WSL: no screen-drawing programs are visible

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can't name the question in other way.

Windows 10 LTSC 1809 (b. 17763.2452). Added the MS Store (LTSC des not contain it by default). Installed WSL and Ubuntu 20.04.

The system runs, but I cant use any programs using screen output other than stdout. Examples: `mc`, `tmux`, `nano` and even `pager/less` (thus `man` is also unavailable). Invoking such command results black windows with blinking cursor in upper left

[image: partial screen after invoking]

(unsure if the picture visible, bu it contains only the part of window header and white cursor on black background)

The program itsef working, and I can exit it using hotkeys or by other means does not require seeing the output. After that the screen isn't restored and I can see the remnants of program's output - 1st page of `man`, status bar of `tmux`, 1st page of `pager`'s output etc. But that output is just a static text in the window.

I had used WSL on my previous job, and never met such problems. Complete WSL removal and re-installaion gave no results

Comment: Haven't run into or heard of anything like this before with WSL. 
 It sounds like the "alternate screen buffer" isn't engaging properly.  This is the mode that those apps switch to for displaying their output.  When they exit the alternate screen, the previous contents of the primary buffer should be returned.  In your case, it doesn't sound like the secondary buffer is getting engaged, so the (bad) output of those programs is getting written over the primary.  What does `echo $TERM` show?  Am I correct in understanding this is the behavior "immediately after installing?"

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds
 xterm-256color
Yes, immediately after installing. I managed to launch WSL in virtual-boxed W11 on Ubuntu host (at home), and all went fine.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Can you try a different one? I'd suggest trying [the new Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701), if you haven't tried it yet. See if those programs work there.

Comment: @cocomac alas, my build does no support installing the WT - it require newer builds (18362.0 or higher). So, I use Windows standard console se by default

Comment: same results are on `tput smcup` invocation (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script ) - the blank screen, but system does not hang: I can type `tput rmcup` to get back

Comment: found almost good workaround, and it seems that MS broke something, in this interesting thread: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7660  I added `export TERM=xterm-color` into `~/.profile` and things seems to be smooth enough.

I tried every terminal from ls /lib/terminfo/* - some produced b/w output, some gave is colors, but F1..F4 keys failed to work etc

Comment: @Troublemaker-DV Excellent - Can you post that as an answer then?  And dang - I think I've seen that Github issue before and even referenced it in an answer, but I couldn't find it this time when looking.  Glad you did!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Here it is :-)

Answer (score 1):

In this interesting thread: [github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7660](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7660) I found almost good workaround, and it seems that MS broke something.

I added `export TERM=xterm-color` into `~/.profile` and things seems to be smooth enough. I tried every terminal from `ls /lib/terminfo/*` - some produced b/w output, some gave is colors, but F1..F4 keys or even arrows failed to work etc

But the screen becomes clear after exiting the program, no previous screen contents preserved, even if it should.
I noted that most complaints were related to **LTSC b17763** and WinServer 2019 based on this build of Win10.

It will be very appreciated, should any one propose real solution for this problem